# What is this politician saying?

Tags: translation, listening-comprehension

At one point in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=riQh4Qpvxm4), Gregor Gysi says something that sounds like “das liegt zum Glück”.

My German is a little rusty (I intend on fixing that shortly), so I’m not sure as to the meaning of that phrase. Is he saying “it’s fortunate”?

Answer (score 4):

The sentence he said was already given, namely:

> Das liegt zum Glück daran, dass die Nazis sich auch nicht besonders vervielfältigen.

The only way I can read this is:

> This is, fortunately, due to the fact that the Nazis, too, don't replicate particularly well.

There is no way I can make sense of this, in particular I reject the interpretation of the uploader (of the video) that he equates Germans and Nazis. My rejection is based on the presence of "zum Glück". If forced to guess, and noting "zum Glück",  I would say he had a very, very bad day and meant:

> Das hat zum Glück zur Folge, dass die Nazis sich auch nicht besonders vervielfältigen,

which translates:

> This, fortunately, implies that the Nazis do not replicate particularly well either.

In my opinion,  confusing these two is, for a native speaker, just as unlikely as confusing "because" and "therefore". I am thus tempted to assume that he was either in terrible shape (I, Ludi, have just been operated and said something strange), or intentionally sowing confusion.

The most important thing for you as a learner is probably the pattern:

> an etwas liegen,

translating:

> To stem from / to come from the fact.

Some examples include:

> Ich spreche Chinesisch. Das liegt auch daran, dass meine Tante aus Taiwan kommt.
>
> Er trinkt keine Milch. Das liegt daran, dass er laktoseintolerant ist.

Comment: I guess he intended to say: "Das liegt _auch_ daran, dass die Nazis sich zum Glück auch nicht besonders _vermehren_." But the way he did it, he made the Nazi's bad reproduction rate the _only_ cause for German population decrease, said that this (and not something else) being the cause would be fortunate, and used the mechanical _vervielfältigen_ instead of _vermehren_, which would have made Orwell's _Big Brother_ (or even Goebbels?) quite proud of him. Fail.

Answer (score 2):

> Das liegt zum Glück daran, dass die Nazis sich auch nicht besonders vervielfältigen.